# Divergence theorem to prove a relation.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I found this problem, I wanna do.
Let $f$ be continuesly differentiable, let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$
Prove $\iint \limits _S \vec f (r) \cdot \vec n \ \Bbb dS = \iiint \limits _B \vec {f'(r)} \cdot \frac {\vec r} r \ \Bbb dV$ where left integral over sphere, right over the ball both of radius $R$.

I tried to apply divergence theorem using that $\vec n=(\frac x r,\frac y r, \frac z r)$. I could not get anything out of that.

I tried to then to work in case $f$ is a vector field, I got the right hand side: $\iiint \frac {f'(r)} {r} \cdot (-2x,-2y,-2z) \ \Bbb dV$.

Any help please. I am also interstate what case we can get if $f$ is scaler. 
I feel like there is a confusion with notation.

Comment: if f is scalar you cannot use the divergence theorem. can you?

Comment: Yes, I multiply f with constant vector

Comment: I have modified part of your question in order for it to make sense mathematically. You put arrows above symbols by writing "\vec {my_symbol}".

Comment: @Alex is f scalar or vector field. if it's scalar, you cannot write $\vec{f'(r)}$ you should write $f'(\vec r)$

Comment: @sepideh: Arrow over the wrong symbol, thank you for noting. Now it's fine ($\vec f$ is a vector function with spherical symmetry, therefore depending only on $r$, not on $\vec r$).

Comment: then @AlexM. how do you define $\vec f'(r)\vec r$ in right-hand side? what kind of multiplication between two vectors? inner?

Comment: @sepideh: Exactly, inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solve this by applying the divergence theorem. Note that $\vec {f(r)}$ is a vector-valued function with spherical symmetry (that is, it does not depend on $\vec r = (x,y,z)$, but only on its norm $r$). By the chain rule, the divergence here will be

$$\operatorname{div} \vec f = \operatorname{div} {(f_x, f_y, f_z)} = f_x ' (r) \frac {\partial r} {\partial x} + f_y ' (r) \frac {\partial r} {\partial y} + f_z ' (r) \frac {\partial r} {\partial z} = (f_x ', f_y ', f_z ') \cdot (\frac x r, \frac y r, \frac z r) = \vec {f'(r)} \cdot \frac {\vec r} r$$

which is precisely the integrand in the right-hand side integral.

Comment: Thanks Alex, your notations corrections makes the problem obvious.

Comment: Would the same result hold if $f$ is scaler, and multiply by constant vector.?

Comment: if f is scalar and n vector, you can not write $f.n$ in left-hand side? what's the notation of the problem exactly? can you post a photo of the problem. Alex M's answer is for the vector case if F is scalar you can not define divergence

Comment: @sepideh: The OP wonders whether the dot $\cdot$ means inner product (as in my solution above) or the product of a scalar function and a vector.

Comment: Sepideh, I agree with what you said. What I am trying to say, if I use the divergence theorm on
$F(x,y,z)=f(x)(c_1,c_2,c_3), \ \ where \  c_i  \ are \ constants$
Now apply the divergence theorm

$\iint \limits _S cf (r). \ \Bbb dS = \iiint \limits _B( c.\bigtriangledown
 f + f \ (\bigtriangledown c))\ \Bbb dV$

second term on right hand side will vanish. then I did not carry out the calculation, as I am not sure if it will yield anything similar.

Comment: @Sepideh, I understand your point, I am just trying to see how to make this work, what changes to make, if its possible to make a similar conclusion for a scaler function.